# How to add a class with number of element to each li element?

Tags: html, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="tab-li">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab-li">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
```

I would like add a class to each of them:

```
<ul class="tab-li">
<li class="li1">one</li>
<li class="li2">two</li>
<li class="li3">three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab-li">
<li class="li1">one</li>
<li class="li2">two</li>
<li class="li3">three</li>
</ul>
```

But I got this:

```
<ul class="tab-li">
<li class="li1">one</li>
<li class="li2">two</li>
<li class="li3">three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab-li">
<li class="li4">one</li>
<li class="li5">two</li>
<li class="li6">three</li>
</ul>
```

My code isn't working because it counts all of them and in the second `<ul>` is continuing the count with the previous `<ul>`. How do I make it independent for each of them?

My jQuery code:

```
$('ul.tab-li li').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('li'+(i == 0 ? i+1:i+1))
  $(this).text($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

Here is an example of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lynsvbgd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work as you expect you need two loops. One through each `.tab-li` and another through the `li` within that element:

```js
$('ul.tab-li').each(function() {
  $(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
    let classname = 'li' + (i + 1);
    $(this).addClass(classname).text(classname);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-li">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab-li">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

If you can guarantee that there are only ever 3 `li` per group then you could use a single loop and the modulo operator:

```js
$('ul.tab-li li').each(function(i) {
  let classname = 'li' + ((i % 3) + 1);
  $(this).addClass(classname).text(classname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-li">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab-li">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This approach won't work if there are nested `ul.tab-li` elements, as `.find()` traverses deeper than one level of the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can used the jQuery `.index()` method to get the index of each list item within its parent.

This approach is robust: it uses only a single loop, will work regardless of the number of list items in a list, and will also still work if there are nested lists.

```js
$('ul.tab-li li').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass(`li${$(this).index() + 1}`);
});
```

```css
li:after {
  content: attr(class);
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab-li">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab-li">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mod operator ;

```
$('ul.tab-li li').each(function(i){
let classNumber = (i % 3) + 1; 
$(this).addClass('li'+classNumber)
$(this).text($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

Comment: This requires that there is always exactly three items in every list.